# PySpark safe column type conversion

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

If I cast a column to a different type then any data that cannot be casted is silently converted to a NULL:

```
df = sc.parallelize([('a', '1'), ('b', 'NAN'), ('c', 'foo'))]) .toDF(['name', 'values'])

df.select( df.values.cast(DoubleType()) ).show()
+------+
|values|
+------+
|   1.0|
|  null|
|  null|
+------+
```

Is there any way to have the conversion produce an error if any value cannot be converted?

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own `udf` for this using python's `float` function which raises an error when the string can't be converted to float:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
@F.udf
def cast_safe(x):
    return float(x)

df.select(cast_safe(df.values).alias("values")).show()
```

> [Stage 5:>                                                          (0 + 3) / 3]17/09/29 09:00:29 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in
>   stage 5.0 (TID 11)
>       org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\spark\spark-2.0.1\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line
>   172, in main
>         File "C:\spark\spark-2.0.1\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line
>   167, in process
>         File "C:\spark\spark-2.0.1\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line
>   106, in 
>         File "C:\spark\spark-2.0.1\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line
>   92, in 
>         File "C:\spark\spark-2.0.1\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line
>   70, in 
>         File "", line 3, in cast_safe
>       ValueError: could not convert string to float: foo

While working correctly if all the elements in the column can be casted safely:

```
df1 = sc.parallelize([('a', '1'), ('b', '0'), ('c', '2.')]) .toDF(['name', 'values'])
df1.select(df1.name, cast_safe(df1.values).alias("values")).show()
+----+------+
|name|values|
+----+------+
|   a|   1.0|
|   b|   0.0|
|   c|   2.0|
+----+------+
```

Comment: Whilst this does work I would prefer to avoid a python function call for every float.